# System Events Logging

Tags: c#, events, system

I need to monitor some system events like shutdown, logoff, lock etc.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. How can I do something before the system get shutdowned, logged off or something like that?
2. When the process get killed via taskmanager do I have any chance todo something before it get closed, without a second process? Probably not or? (not so important)

What I have so far:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
        SystemEvents.SessionEnded += SystemEvents_SessionEnded;
        SystemEvents.EventsThreadShutdown += SystemEvents_ThreadShutdown;
        SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;
    }

    private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Log("PowerMode Suspend: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
        }
        else if(e.Mode == PowerModes.Resume)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Log("PowerMode Resume: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
        }
    }

    private void SystemEvents_ThreadShutdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Log("EventThread Shutdown: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
    }

    private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Log("Locked the machine: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
        }
        else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Log("Unlocked the machine: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
        }
        else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogoff)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Log("Logged of the machine: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
        }
    }

    private void SystemEvents_SessionEnded(object sender, SessionEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Log("Shutdown of the machine: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
        }
        else if (e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.Logoff)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Log("Logoff of the machine: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
        }
    }
```

The sleep just should emulate some actions todo before this events.
Only the Windows Lock & Window Closed does work, the other ones not, probably because the program is already closed.

Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `Thread.Sleep`'s? My guess is that you just don't have that 5 seconds when OS gets shutting down ...

Comment: Hey, no I didn't test it because I need this time. Isn't there any way to delay the shutdown etc.?

Comment: I don't know so far, but I'd recommend you to remove that `sleep`'s to figure out that it's not working because of 5 sec is not enough or because of some another reason(for example, maybe that events are not invoked at all). *One step at a time*

Comment: BTW, you can try to handle `SessionEnding` event and to put `Thread.Sleep` there in order to see whether it delays shutting down or not.

Comment: This is probably dependent on windows versions and installed hotfix. Last I read that they changed windows to only give a very short time on shutdown to execute code.